# How to display user_nicename and usermeta values by custom query in Wordpress?

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am trying to display user_nicename and one of usermeta values where meta_key is description. My query is given below:

```
<?php
$querystr = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->users, $wpdb->usermeta
        WHERE $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id 
        AND $wpdb->usrmeta.meta_key = 'description' 
     ";

$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>

<?php global $retrieved_data; foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->user_nicename;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->meta_value;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

My final output should be displayed inside a table which will look something like below: 
[image]

But I am in confusion how to do that. I am facing problem for both sql syntax and displaying data inside the table. Sorry for this easy question, I am still a learner. Can anyone help me in here? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users, since you are using WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

To do that with WordPress functions, you can try that

```
$users = get_users();


?>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Customer Details</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($users as $u) {?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($u->display_name);?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($u->description); // retrieve the meta "description"?>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php }?>

    </table>

<?php
```